# Search for Multiple strings in a model swift data model

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, model, uisearchbar

I have little experience with programming in general and I'm working on an inventory app on the side to try understand the basics. So far everything is going well; however, searching for strings in my cell stumped me. Could someone please point me in the right direction. The code I have now allows me to search for ".mod" in ascending order and then refreshes the tableview with the cells that contain the value im looking for. What cant grasp is how to search for all values in my model like .mod, .man, .qty...etc.

This is my current model:

```swift
import Foundation
import UIKit

class MasterDataModel{

    var id: String?
    var man: String?
    var mod: String?
    var loc: String?
    var qty: String?
    var upc: String?
    var con: String?
    var dec: String?
    
    
    
    
    
    init(id: String?,
         man: String?,
         mod: String?,
         loc: String?,
         qty: String?,
         upc: String?,
         con: String?,
         dec: String?) {
        
        self.id = id;
        self.man = man;
        self.mod = mod;
        self.loc = loc;
        self.qty = qty;
        self.upc = upc;
        self.con = con;
        self.dec = dec;
        
       
    }

}
```

and this is the search function that I am using. NOTE: This was addopted from GitHub to try get basic functionality and understanding.

https://github.com/HaMaDaRaOuF/UISearchBar-Firabse

```swift
func searchBar(\_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {

        print("\(searchText)")
    
        //MARK: - Basic search function adopted from https://github.com/HaMaDaRaOuF/UISearchBar-Firabse by HaMaDaRaOuF
        currentModelArray.removeAll(keepingCapacity: false)
        let searchPredicate = searchBar.text!
        currentModelArray = masterData.filter({$0.mod?.range(of: searchPredicate) != nil})
        
        currentModelArray.sort {$0.mod! < $1.mod!}
        isSearching = (currentModelArray.count == 0) ? false: true
            self.tblMasterData.reloadData()
    
    
    }

}
```

Any assistance would be appreciated. I'm still VERY new to this stuff so I apologize in advance if I ask any stupid questions or my terminology is incorrect.

Comment: You can just add more conditions in your `filter` function.

Comment: Do you hace a ecxample I can reference?

Answer (score 1):

Solved by adding `||` between each item.

```
currentModelArray = masterData.filter { $0.mod!.contains(searchPredicate) || $0.man!.contains(searchPredicate) || $0.dec!.contains(searchPredicate) || $0.loc!.contains(searchPredicate) || $0.con!.contains(searchPredicate) || $0.dec!.contains(searchPredicate) || $0.upc!.contains(searchPredicate)}
```